# Ionic cordova-plugin-screen-orientation ios orientation lock sometimes makes screen narrow

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When I change the orientation in the application it sometimes makes the application view narrow. Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjiLS.jpg.

I use this the cordova-plugin-screen-orientation lockOrientation method to change the orientation and sometimes it doesn't resize the window correctly. This seems to happen at random and often enough that it is a problem.

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) ScreenOrientation.lockOrientation('portrait');
```

Is there any fix or workaround for this problem?

Cordova, ionic and the plugin version in use:
cordova: 6.4.0
ionic: 2.1.18
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation: 1.4.2

I am developing on windows and have no access to mac, so I don't think I can debug this in any way. I use ionic cloud to create the package for ios.

Let me know if any additional information is needed! Thanks!

**Edit:** This only happens with iPhone, I am testing it with latest ios and iPhone 5s

Comment: sounds it is only occurs in iPhone ?

Comment: Yes, it only occurs in iPhone, edited the post to include that.